# How to get deep-equality of keys in ES6 Map? Alternative to using complex object as ES6 Map key?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is some example Javascript (ES6) code that does not do what one might intuitively imagine.

```
const exampleMap = new Map([[{a: 1}, 2]]);
console.log(exampleMap.get({a: 1}));
```

As it turns out, this prints `undefined`. Why? The reasoning is covered in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37188093/904117). Per [the MDN entry for Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), `Map` uses `===` for key equality. And, per [the MDN entry for `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), `Object`s are compared by reference equality.

That's all fine and good. It does exactly what the docs say it should. Unfortunately, what the above code is trying to do would be quite useful, even if it isn't the actual behavior per the spec.

How can I use `Map`, or what should I use instead of `Map`, to get a key-value lookup where the keys are compared by object deep-equality semantics?

Comment: "object deep-equality semantics"? You mean stringification? Then stringify it, and a simple plain Object will do. `{a:1}` is semantically different than `{a:1}` in javascript.

Comment: See also [Define a custom hash() method for use with ES6 Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31582852/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own function, where you pass through the map (`m`) you want to get the value of, and a `key` you want to search in the map. You can then stringify your key, such that you can search the keys in your map and compare them against this stringified key

```js
const exampleMap = new Map([[{a: 1}, 2]]);

const getMapVal = (m, key) => {
  const strKey = JSON.stringify(key);
  return m.get(Array.from(m.keys()).find((k) => JSON.stringify(k) === strKey));
}

console.log(getMapVal(exampleMap, {a: 1})); // 2 (gives undefined if key doesn't exists)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that does a deep equality check. It relies on `JSON.stringify` though so it might be a performance issue for very large object keys. This also updates the `Map` prototype for use in the same way as `.get`.

```js
Object.defineProperty(Map.prototype, 'deepCheck', {
  value: function(lookupKey) {
    let lookupValue;
    const lookupKeyStr = JSON.stringify(lookupKey);
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
    }

    const iterator = this.entries();
    let result = null;


    while (true) {
      result = iterator.next();
      if (result.done) {
        break;
      }
      if (JSON.stringify(result.value[0]) === lookupKeyStr) {
        lookupValue = result.value[1];
      }
    }

    return lookupValue;
  }
});

const exampleMap = new Map([[{a: 1}, 2]]);

console.log(exampleMap.deepCheck({a: 1}));
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to somehow compare against or get a reference to the exact object that was used as the Map key. One option would be to iterate over the Map's `entries`, and check for one whose key has an `a` value of 1:

```js
const exampleMap = new Map([[{a: 1}, 2]]);
const foundEntry = [...exampleMap.entries()]
  .find(([key, val]) => key.a === 1);
  
console.log(
  foundEntry
  ? foundEntry[1]
  : 'Not found!'
);
```

Another approach:

```js
const exampleMap = new Map([[{a: 1}, 2]]);
const foundKey = [...exampleMap.keys()]
  .find(key => key.a === 1);
  
console.log(
  foundKey
  ? exampleMap.get(foundKey)
  : 'Not found!'
);
```